# How to solve a runtime symbol lookup error?

Tags: opengl, ubuntu-14.04, glew, undefined-symbol

I have been working on a pet project for a while, and I recently encountered a runtime symbol lookup error. As the error itself does not provide much information I have no idea how to solve it.

I am using Eclipse Mars.

I include the following headers:

```
#include <GL/glew.h> //glew-1.12.0
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h> //glfw-3.1.1
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <math.h>
```

My console output looks normal when I build the project.

```
12:05:00 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project Game ****
make all 
Building file: ../main.cpp
Invoking: Cross G++ Compiler
g++ -I/usr/include/libdrm -I/usr/local/include -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -    fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.d" -o "main.o"         "../main.cpp"
Finished building: ../main.cpp

Building target: Game
Invoking: Cross G++ Linker
g++ -L/usr/local/lib -o "Game"  ./main.o   -lGL -lGLEW -lGLU -lglfw3 -lX11 -lXcursor -lXi -lXinerama -lXrandr -lXxf86vm -lpthread
Finished building target: Game


12:05:01 Build Finished (took 567ms)
```

But when I try to run it I get the following error:

```
/home/lokko/git/buum/Game/Debug/Game: symbol lookup error:/home/lokko/git/buum/Game/Debug/Game: undefined symbol: __glewClipControl
```

I am a hobbyist programmer and everithing I know I have learned myself so it would be nice if the anwser was as clear as possible about what I need to do to get this to work. The specific function causing the problem is

```
glClipControl(GLenum origin,GLenum depth);
```

Edit:
I am running opengl 4.5 on Nvidia 840m and using proprietary Nvidia drivers. (349)

Solution:
So everything started to work after I the last Ubuntu update. Don`t know what it was. The last update before that was less than 24 hours ago. I wouldn`t consider this an actual solution and I will post when this issue returns.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're running into is, that OpenGL has to classes of symbols: OS ABI defined symbols, which are symbols and functionality which is asserted to be available for *any* OpenGL implementation running on the system (for Windows this is OpenGL-1.1, for Linux LSB4 OpenGL-1.2 and with the recently released LSB5 it's OpenGL-2.1).

*Anything* that's outside of those asserted to be available ABIs may be not available and must be first tested for presence, then loaded at runtime through the OpenGL extension mechanism. This covers core OpenGL versions higher than what's specified in the ABI, but also vendor specific extensions. In your case `glClipControl` is a function that got introduced with OpenGL-4.5 (which at the time of writing this is the highest OpenGL version around).

So for this function to be available you need a fairly recent GPU (well, everthing built by AMD and NVidia after 2012 should do the trick) **and** you need the latest drivers for that GPU.

That error is telling you, that the function you'd like to use is not supported by either your GPU or the OpenGL implementation you have.

Now in case of a run-of-the-mill Linux you're likely using the Mesa drivers (which go only up to OpenGL-3.x so far; OpenGL-4.x support will be there eventually) or a rather outdated vendor proprietary driver that's not OpenGL-4.5 capable.

Solution:

- Check that your GPU is not made by Intel (there are only Mesa drivers for Intel GPUs)
- Check that your GPU actually supports OpenGL-4.5
- Download the latest proprietary drivers for that GPU and install those

Comment: This is not my problem. I should have added that I have a Nvidia 840m and am currently running OpenGL-4.5. Noveau drivers have been blacklisted and the developer environment is running on the Nvidia graphics. I get no compile time errors.  The problem is that I cant even find any literature that could help me solve this.

Comment: @Andreas: Well, this is not a "standard programming" problem. As I already explained, OpenGL has two kinds of symbols. Core ABI symbols, and extended symbols. And the symbol you're requesting is one of the extended ones on your system. `__glewClipControl` is the symbol GLEW loads glClipControl into and aliases (that this `__glew…` prefix is added is to avoid namespace pollution). The only literature you could read upon that topic is about the *OpenGL extension loading mechanism*: https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Load_OpenGL_Functions

Comment: @Andreas: If all drivers are properly installed make sure that `glewInit()` is executed successfully. Note that most Linux distributions are rather braindead when it comes to properly set OpenGL libGL.so paths (Gentoo is the only distribution I know, that gets it mostly right). Use `glxinfo` to check that the GLX `client vendor` is also NVidia.